# What's the Cygwin/Red Hat equivalent to Debian's manpages-dev, manpages-posix-dev?

Tags: ubuntu, cygwin, posix, redhat, manpage

I'm using Cygwin, and just discovered to my dismay that the package naming scheme is derived from Red Hat. I need the development man pages, called [manpages-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/manpages-dev) and [manpages-posix-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/manpages-posix-dev) on Debian-based distros, and can't locate the Cygwin/RH equivalents. What are they?

If they're not available, what's the canonical documentation to use in their place for Cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fair number of C library manpages in the cygwin-doc package, but it's by no means complete. Cygwin aims for POSIX and Linux compatibility though, so the POSIX standard at http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799 and the glibc documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual are appropriate sources. The Linux manpages at http://linux.die.net are useful too.

Documentation of Cygwin-specific functions as well as a list of standard functions that have not been implemented can be found at http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/cygwin-api.html.

Answer (score 3):

Cygwin package `cygwin-doc` is equivalent to `manpages-dev`, and `man-pages-posix` is equivalent to `manpages-posix-dev`.